# c# System.InvalidOperationException when tyring to make a queue

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a queue to send data to a API after the API gives a sign of life.

System.InvalidOperationException in the following code:

```
 private void sendHandler()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!sendQueueActive && sendQueue.Count >= 1)
            {
                sendQueueActive = true;
                foreach (relays relays in sendQueue)
                {                        
                    dynamic result = IoLogikApiConnector.put("io/relay", relays);
                    int code = result.error.code;
                    if (code != 0)
                    {
                        _log.logErrorToApi("Cannot write to IoLogik", "Error code:" + result, _deviceID);
                        _device.logErrorToApi();
                        sendQueue.Remove(relays);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        _device.logConnectedToApi();
                        sendQueue.Remove(relays);
                    }
                    sendQueueActive = false;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, *where* in the following code..? What is the exception message?

Comment: Its in the foreach loop, The program is writing data to the List while this code wants to remove the "relays" in the QueueList.

Comment: What's the type of `sendQueue`? There is no `Remove` method on `Queue<T>`.

Comment: Its a list of a custom object.

Comment: If it's due to removing items in the collection while in the foreach loop (which it probably is), the exception message would have told you the exact problem. Always check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing items from the queue whilst using a foreach. Never a good thing.

Better to write

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

private void sendHandler()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (!sendQueueActive && sendQueue.Count >= 1)
        {
            sendQueueActive = true;

            // MAKE A COPY FIRST
            var sendQueueCopy = sendQueue.ToList();

            foreach (relays relays in sendQueueCopy)
            {                        
                dynamic result = IoLogikApiConnector.put("io/relay", relays);
                int code = result.error.code;
                if (code != 0)
                {
                    _log.logErrorToApi("Cannot write to IoLogik", "Error code:" + result, _deviceID);
                    _device.logErrorToApi();
                    sendQueue.Remove(relays);
                }
                else
                {

                    _device.logConnectedToApi();
                    sendQueue.Remove(relays);
                }
                sendQueueActive = false;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
    }
}
```

but even better use a thread safe queue.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx

Here's the cut and paste example from the above link

```
        // A bounded collection. It can hold no more 
        // than 100 items at once.
        BlockingCollection<Data> dataItems = new BlockingCollection<Data>(100);


        // A simple blocking consumer with no cancellation.
        Task.Run(() => 
        {
            while (!dataItems.IsCompleted)
            {

                Data data = null;
                // Blocks if number.Count == 0
                // IOE means that Take() was called on a completed collection.
                // Some other thread can call CompleteAdding after we pass the
                // IsCompleted check but before we call Take. 
                // In this example, we can simply catch the exception since the 
                // loop will break on the next iteration.
                try
                {
                    data = dataItems.Take();
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException) { }

                if (data != null)
                {
                    Process(data);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nNo more items to take.");
        });

        // A simple blocking producer with no cancellation.
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (moreItemsToAdd)
            {
                Data data = GetData();
                // Blocks if numbers.Count == dataItems.BoundedCapacity
                dataItems.Add(data);
            }
            // Let consumer know we are done.
            dataItems.CompleteAdding();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but sendQueue.ToList(); is not available?

Comment: What exactly is the type of sendQueue ?? I assume it should implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Its a List containing an object

Comment: Can you please show the declaration. Which library / namespace does it come from.

Comment: `using System.Collections.Generic; 
 private List<relays> sendQueue = new List<relays>(); `

Comment: Then it definitely has a ToList() extension method. You need to add `using System.Linq`  But as I said you should be using a thread safe queue.